# how many ways are there to choose a Board of Directors consisting of seven distinct people?

Tags: combinatorics

If there are n>=7 people in a company that are vying to become a member of the Board of directors, how many ways are there to choose a Board of Directors consisting of seven distinct people? 
I'm having a real trouble attempting this question, since I was not given an upperbound. For example, if n=10, then the answer will be 10!/3!.

Comment: The answer is not $10!/3!$, unless the individual positions are **named**.

Comment: There are seven different positions.

Comment: If the positions are named (President, VP, Lies manager, and so on) then the number will be $(n)(n-1)\cdots (n-6)$, or equivalently $\frac{n!}{7!}$. But Boards of Directors usually don't necessarily work like that. There will be one or two named positions.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I just didn't name them in this example. In your answer(n!/7!), if you take out 7!, you are left with (n)(n-1)(n-2).

Comment: Sorry, bad typo towards the end of my comment. It is $\frac{n!}{(n-7)!}$.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, the general answer is $n \choose 7$ if the positions are identical, $7!{n \choose 7}=\frac {n!}{(n-7)!}$ if the positions are distinct

Comment: So, it doesn't matter if n is at least 7?

Comment: Yes, it matters.  The combination will be zero if $n \lt 7$  If the positions are distinct, you need to multiply by $7!$, which would match your $\frac {10!}{3!}$

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how you arrived at 7!(n C 7). Can you please explain?

Comment: The $n \choose 7$ chooses seven people out of $n$ without regard to order.  The factor $7!$ puts them in order.

Comment: Oh, I get it. It just didn't click at first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on [Ross's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/656615/106234), taking [André's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656613#comment-1381886) (*"But Boards of Directors usually don't necessarily work like that. There will be one or two named positions."*) into account, let's generalize.

There are $n$ people, vying for $k$ positions on a Board of Directors, out of which $m$ positions are named.
First, we have to pick the members of the board. There are $n \choose k$ ways of doing that.

Then we have to assign the named functions. There are $\frac{k!}{(k-m)!}$ ways of filling those, since we don't care about the order of unnamed functions, but we care about the order of the named functions, because they aren't interchangable.

That leaves us with a total of $${n \choose k} \cdot \frac{k!}{(k-m)!} = \frac{n!}{(n-k)! \cdot (k-m)!}$$ where of course $m \leq k \leq n$.